# Batch Hex to Asciic makes the string useless?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I belive i found a nice way to send out a command line to multiple batch windows at once, here is how i see it going:

1. Using Set with /p allows me to user input a string that i save as message
2. Exporting it to its own bat file with "Echo set command=%message% >command.bat
3. Using echo to type out ftp information and then run it with "Ftp -s:upload.txt ftp.example.com
4. This uploads it to my webhotel where im gonna use a bitadmin.exe to download the file
5. Then running command.bat and ensuring that if the string %command% isnt the same before it runs the command

It's all working fine and what not, but i feel like my ftp name/password is too exposed to anyone that has the IQ to "*Right-Click*, *Edit*" and inspect the code. I've come to the point where i'm trying to make it harder to really get it just by looking at the batch file.

So far i converted my password into HEX and using a fancy batch file convert it back into a string from a batch file i call, and then export it with the ftp connection file. It works all up untill the batch reads the ftp connection file and gets stuck on "requiring password" even though when i check my ftp connection file then the password is correctly typed in the right place, no additional spaces or odd stuff. But it wont work untill i deleted the line and typed it in my self. (The other way that i was considering  using a Batch to exe program but that just runs the batch file in the temp folder, everyone knows that) The hex password i use here is just "password"

Code so far:

```
@Echo Off

:Start

Rem (1)Set/(2)Export Message

Rem (1)
Set /p message=

Rem (2)
Echo set run=%message% >command.bat

Rem (1)Decode Hex/(2)Running hex output/(3)Acces FTP service

Rem (1)
Start HEX.bat 70617373776f7264

Rem (2)
Call CODE.bat
Del /Q CODE.bat

Rem (3)
Echo darkrock> upload.txt
Echo %code%>> upload.txt
Echo asc>>upload.txt
Echo put command.bat>> upload.txt
Echo quit >> upload.txt
Ftp -s:upload.txt ftp.example.com

Goto :Start
```

The hex converter comes here:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set Caret=^^
set ControlChar={SOH} {STX} {ETX} {EOT} {ENQ} {ACK} {BEL} {BS} {HT} {LF} {VT} {FF} {CR} {SO} {SI} {DLE} {XON}
set ControlChar=%ControlChar% {DC2} {XOFF} {DC4} {NAK} {SYN} {ETB} {CAN} {EM} {SUB} {ESC} {FS} {GS} {RS} {US}
set AsciiChar= !"#$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set AsciiChar=!AsciiChar!@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]!Caret!_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{^|}~
set AsciiChar=!AsciiChar!€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿
set AsciiChar=!AsciiChar!ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ

set HexCode=%1
call :Conversion
echo Hex:   %1
echo Dec:   %DecimalCode%
echo Ascii: !AsciiCode!
echo Bin:   %BinaryCode%
cls
goto :EOF


:Conversion
set DecimalCode=
set AsciiCode=
set BinaryCode=
:ConvertHex
   set /A Decimal=0x%HexCode:~0,2%, DecChar=Decimal-32
   set DecimalCode=%DecimalCode%%Decimal%,
   if %Decimal% lss 32 (
      if %Decimal% equ 0 (
         set AsciiCode=!AsciiCode!{NUL}
      ) else (
         for /F "tokens=%Decimal%" %%c in ("%ControlChar%") do set AsciiCode=!AsciiCode!%%c
      )
   ) else (   
      set AsciiCode=!AsciiCode!!AsciiChar:~%DecChar%,1!
   )
   call :DecToBin
   set BinaryCode=%BinaryCode%%Binary%,
   set HexCode=%HexCode:~2%
   if defined HexCode goto ConvertHex
exit /B

:DecToBin
set Binary=
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do (
   set /A "Bit=Decimal&1, Decimal>>=1"
   set Binary=!Bit!!Binary!
)        
echo set code=%AsciiCode% >Code.bat
exit /B
```

Thx in advance! :) It might be me that missed something in the code but i belive i tried by best the last two days compared to being busy with collage.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077030/dos-batch-script-to-convert-string-2-hex/35077565#35077565) question ?

Comment: The hex convertion works as a charm, i dont think thats the problem.

Comment: What kind of collage are you making? Security by obfuscation is not really security. Something like sftp might be needed.

Comment: That collage wasn't on the list but sounds interesting ;) and all in all the original idea behind the batch file works. all i want is to make it harder to find the password.